# How does Wordpress Child theme work?

Tags: wordpress

I am in the process of developing a Wordpress theme. I have heard that creating a child theme is a must. But I have seen premium and free templates which do not have reference to any parent theme. Now if I want to export the created theme to another site how can I do that? Copy both the parent and child theme?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to create a child theme only if you want to change anything in the default wordpress theme (like TwentyEleven or TwentyTwelve).

If you're developing completely new theme for Wordpress you shouldn't create any child themes. You'll be able to export that theme by copying its own folder.

Comment: You can create your own child themes that are children of your own theme. No restriction on default WP themes (e.g. Twenty Twelve) there. Though yes, they are the most extended themes in WordPress when using child themes.